# Can we use 'such as for example'?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it possible to use '*such as..*' and *'for example,*' in a sentence like this:

> "Device and method for cleaning containers such as for example agricultural crates"

Can we use '*such as..*' and '*for example,*' together in a sentence?

Comment: Since they mean the same thing -- pick one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 2):

"Such as for example" is saying the same thing twice.

When you are saying, "containers such as bottles, pots and jars", what you are doing is providing **examples** of containers. So saying "for example" is redundant.

You might hear people saying this, but if you were writing an article for a newspaper, your editor would cross out either "such as" or "for example".

M Palmer said, up there in the comments, "It may sometimes, but not always, suggest that the speaker is having difficulty thinking of an example"—and this is precisely because that this implies that someone says, "such as..... er..... um..... for example"—the speaker simply **repeats** the same thing in different words.

So one of those is completely unnecessary. It's not a language mistake, it's a stylistical mistake called [pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, strictly speaking. However, it would have to be somewhat separated from the sentence:

> Device and method for cleaning containers such as, for example, 
>   agricultural crates

Keep in mind that this is an informal way of writing, though.

Comment: Although it may seem okay, using both of them in one sentence, wouldn't be advisable. It could invoke a hint of confusion, as well as an unwanted repetition for either of the terms.

Comment: I'm a native speaker in the UK, and it doesn't seem at all unusual to me. It may sometimes, but not always, suggest that the speaker is having difficulty thinking of an example, but it will be understood perfectly fine.

Comment: Not necessarily. Maybe to a native speaker there isn't anything ambiguous and confusing with the usage of both terms in a single sentence. But to a non-native speaker, it may bring about a doubt of added repetition. The main objective of a language is to keep things simple, so as to convey something with minimum confusion and maximum clarity.

Comment: I'm not saying it is wrong, but isn't it better to use a simpler sentence, especially for people who are non-native to English, in their learning phase.

Comment: I do understand what you mean, but a native speaker is not unlikely to use this phrase. Telling someone that it's wrong will only create confusion when they eventually do hear it.

Comment: Also, thinking about it, they're not exactly the same thing. 'such as' is actually a remnant of old English - 'such' means 'sharing the properties of'. So, 'such as agricultural crates' refers to something with similar properties to an agricultural crate. 'for example an agricultural crate' simply means that an agricultural crate is one thing that statement is true for, but something else might also fit that is completely different. I. E. You might also use the device or method in order to clean a car, which is not expressed by 'such as'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65530/discussion-between-varun-kn-and-m-palmer).

Comment: It,s fine, but needs the commas, agree with M Palmer.